# Swipe left only in landscape

Tags: ios, swift, uiswipegesturerecognizer

I make an app is working in portrait and landscape left et i would like to know how the swipe left only work in landscape left and the swipe up only in portrait.

I do this in viewDidLoad:

```
// swipe left
let left = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(swipe))
left.direction = .left
self.swipeUp.addGestureRecognizer(left)
```

Answer (score 1):

Check the orientation in your action function:

```
@objc private func swipe() {
    guard UIDevice.current.orientation == .landscapeLeft else {
        return
    }
    // your code
}
```

Comment: Yes but when i try this, the swipe in portrait mode doesn't work.. i want the swipe up work only in portrait mode and swipe left only in landscape left.

Comment: Convert the guard statment to a if-else statment, like
`if orientation == .left {} else if orientation == .portrait {}`

Answer (score 0):

You can also use gesture recognizer delegate.

```swift
class ViewController: UIViewController, UIGestureRecognizerDelegate {

    func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let left = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action:#selector(swipe))
        left.direction = .left
        self.swipeUp.addGestureRecognizer(left)
    }

    func gestureRecognizerShouldBegin(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool { 
        let gesture = gestureRecognizer as? UISwipeGestureRecognizer

        switch uidevice.orientation {
            case .portrait: return gesture.direction == .up
            case .landscape: return gesture.direction == .left
            default : return false
        }
    }
}
```